# Could someone explain what do these messages mean

Tags: modeling

I tried to export 1 model in two different formats but when I did these messages showed up, 1 for each format. What do they mean an how do I fix this so I can export.
[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

[![enter image description here][5]][5]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q21RJ.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Not very knowledgeable on python but it looks like your code is trying to do something with a 'Name' attribute when the 'NoneType' Object doesn't have such a thing. If you are using code from a past version of blender it might be relaying on an attribute that is not there by default anymore and needs to be done differently. If you are the one that wrote the code then presumably you didn't create that attribute or the function that does didn't work properly

Comment: Which exporter did you use?

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: I used .tmd2 and .tmd

Answer (score 3):

This code is trying to access the **Name** of an **Image** attached to a **Node**, but it has found a node which doesn't have an Image associated to it, so when it tries to access the Image, it finds a NoneType which does not have an attribute called Name, so the code crashes.

Check your materials and make sure that all Image Texture nodes have an Image attached. Since an Image Texture node with no associated image is effectively useless, you can safely delete any you find.

Comment: That could be it, I'm just no sure how to find the materials.

Answer (score 2):

The script tries to access `node.image.name` but `node.image` contains a `NoneType`, i.e. `None` which has no attribute `name`, hence the `AttributeError`.

Somewhere you have a node with an image property without an actual image in your materials. To find where, you can run this little script to avoid searching for it manually.

```
import bpy

for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
        if hasattr(node, 'image') and node.image == None:
            print('in material "' + mat.name + '" node "' + node.name + '" has no image set!')
```

Comment: Hey I wanted to respond a while ago I j is just couldn't so don't forget about me . I tried to run the script but it didn't work. I don't usually run them. Do you what I did wrong. Also how would I find materials manually incase the script still doesn't work

Comment: What was the problem when running the script? Did you get an error message? Regarding finding materials manually (just one way to do it): create a dummy object and go to the `Material Properties` tab, to the left of `New` you can find a materials dropdown which will show all materials. Select one after another and fix your nodes. When done, delete the dummy object.

Comment: Let me give a screenshot

Comment: Okay I added some more screenshots above.

Comment: Ok, we are getting closer. As the message states _"python script failed check the message in the system console"_ go to `Window > Toggle System Console` and copy paste the error. And please crop your screenshots. At this point, it may be easier if you would share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Where should I copy and paste the error? Also I think I found the materials so I added more screenshots above. If I did how do I check for images

Comment: Of course you should paste the error here, either in the question or in a comment so we can see it. You can inspect materials in the `Shader Editor` and need to find all nodes which can have images (for example the `Image Texture` node). Please get some basic understandings of how to use Blender first, you have been given enough instructions to solve your problem. And please fix your question, its screwed up now. Again, it would be easier if you would just upload your blend file here: https://blend-exchange.com/